# CSS min-height not working properly

Tags: html, css

Here is the situation, I have this html:

```
<div id='main'>
    <div id='menu'>
        Menu Items Here
    </div>
    <div id='cont'>
        Content Here
        <div id='footer'>Some Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS here:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   width : 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#main{
    overflow : auto;
    background-color: yellow;
    width : 100%;
    min-height : 100%;
}

#menu {
    background-color: red;
    float : left;
    width : 300px;
}

#cont {
    margin-left : 300px;
    float : right;
    background-color: orange;
    width : 100px;
    min-height : 100%;
    height: auto !important; /*min-height hack*/
    height: 100%;            /*min-height hack*/
}
```

What I want to do basically is #cont div must have a min height of 100% (if I have small content) but will extend if have longer content.

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: The width size is just temporary for now.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. You want min-height to be 100% of what?

Comment: @CameronMartin, basically i want the height of #cont to fit the screen if the content is small. and will extend if has longer content

Comment: @YogeshSaroya you dont have a grasp of what happened dont you? It is not the grammar or word of choice . It is the effort we are looking on your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may work:

```
#main{
    height : 100%;
}
#cont {
    min-height : 100%;
    /* Without the hacks */
}
```

Comment: I tried this but if the content of #cont is longer than the window, the content shows but the style is still 100%. (the overflow has no style.)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Tried in Chrome and IE (10 - 8).

Comment: Future readers - depending on your circumstances, you may need to add `html, body{height:100%}`, as demonstrated below by Cameron Martin.

Answer (score 3):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/W6tvW/2/

```
<div id='main'>
    <div id='menu'>
        Menu Items Here
    </div>
    <div id='cont'>
        Content Here
        <div id='footer'>Some Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>

html, body {
   height: 100%;
   width : 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#main{
    overflow : auto;
    background-color: yellow;
    min-height : 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#menu {
    background-color: red;
    float : left;
    width : 300px;
}

#cont {
    margin-left : 300px;
    background-color: orange;
    min-height : 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

If you want the footer to stay at the bottom:

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you are using min-height:100% which means 'make the minimum height of this box be the height of it'

you would be better using a pixel value (e.g., make #menu and #cont min-height:400px;)

if you want to make them both the height of the tallest one, then you'll need some jquery:

```
if (jQuery('#menu').height() < jQuery('#cont').height()) {
    // the cont is bigger than the menu
    jQuery('#menu').css("height", jQuery('#cont').height());
}
```

Comment: Not true - min-height:100% would mean make the minimum height the height of the containing block, according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp).

Comment: @GregBell MDN > w3schools